# a button to do two operations

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a button to do two operations. And each time it's clicked, it will do one of the operations. But this button does both operations together. I want this button to be correct. And if you can make this code with javascript 6

```html
$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function () {
 $("i", this).toggleClass("agency-top-sort agency-btn-sort");
 customSort(FlyList,'price',true); 
 console.log(FlyList);
 $('#flights').updateDom(FlyList, {
  animate: true,
 });

});



$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function () {
 $("i", this).toggleClass("agency-top-sort agency-btn-sort");
 customSort(FlyList,'price',false); 
 console.log(FlyList);
 $('#flights').updateDom(FlyList, {
  animate: true,
 });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are calling the button twice expecting only the right one to run.

I changed it so there is a variable that is changed every time the button is clicked.

I know you said you wanted it changed to javascript6, but I kept it jQuery since **updatedom** is a jQuery function.

```js
var price_sort = false;

$(document).on('click', '.sortByPrice', function () {
  $("i", this).toggleClass("agency-top-sort agency-btn-sort");
  customSort(FlyList,'price',price_sort); 

  price_sort = !price_sort;

  console.log(FlyList);
  $('#flights').updateDom(FlyList, {
    animate: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="sortByPrice">TEST</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your correct answer. It's not a problem. I just want this code to be in javascript. I do not want to use special jQuery functions. I just want to be right in any way in JavaScript code

Comment: If you don't any jquery you will want to embed the source code of or link to updateDom so users can see the entire function and can assist in converting it.

Comment: In fact, I want this code to be turned into javascript. In any way, just jQuery code will be converted to javascript 6. Or the answer that gives the jquery code. Answer the JavaScript with the same code. That is, both codes do one thing.

Comment: If you don't post the source for updateDom, no one will be able to convert it to plain javascript 6.